# php codeigniter использование своей функции в шаблоне

Tags: php, codeigniter

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста как в CodeIgniter в самом шаблоне использовать свою функцию? Я  понимаю, что это не красиво и не правильно, но иначе придется разбирать массив вот такого вида:

> категория1
> ----категория2
> -----категория3
> ------категория4
> -------категория5

И потом опять собрать в том же виде, но с добавлением доп. ключа к каждому массиву.
Пытался прописать `$this->myfunct($id)` не срабатывало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полный бред, зачем в шаблоне использовать часть модели?

Сделай лучше нормальную модель, которая обработает тебе данные в нужном русле и потом рендери в шаблон или если у тебя 2 разных вывода, то в разные шаблоны.

Зачем писать часть данных в вывод???

Comment: Пришлось сделать немного по другому способ тяжелый но практичный, изначально вытащил из второй базы весь контент занес нужные данные в  отдельный массив а после уже в цикле построение меню использовал еще один цикл в котором идет выборка нужного контента. Изначально хотел занести все данные в массив но т.к массив супер пупер многомерный с утра мозгов не хватило придумать как его обработать.

Answer (score 0):

А причем тут модель, вы имели ввиду контроллер ?

**2Jokerofgod** Попробуйте так, никогда в отображениях функции не использовал, но должно помочь:

```
function myFunction()
{

    $CI = &get_instance();
    //тут тело функции

}
```

А если вам нужна обычная функция не использующая методы CI то, проблем тут вообще быть не должно, используйте ее как и в обычном php скрипте, предварительно обрамив ее в php теги, но как уже не однократно тут писалось, использование всякого рода php вставок и действий в отображении это плохой тон!

Comment: >> вставок и действий в отображении это плохой тон!
Полностью согласен, но только через полтора часа до меня дошло как можно этого избежать, хоть способ получился и тяжелый.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Создай свой хелпер.

Comment: Спасибо, в последующих вариантах так и делал, или же просто прогонял массив используя foreach с ключем и как бы перезаписывал массив заново.